# Ubuntu files are not accessible through Windows 8

Tags: windows, filesystem, windows-8, ntfs

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 64-bit alongside genuine Windows 8.

I can access both through Grub boot menu (Though the Windows 8 is shown as 'Windows 8 UEFI recovery'), but the problem is, when I save something in Ubuntu on a drive, I can't find the file after booting in to Windows 8.

The problem is worst when I try to access the F drive from Windows 8 it shows "*F:\ is not accessible. The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable*". This drive is NOT the drive where Ubuntu was installed.

What should I do now?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu Mansib! You said "when I save something in Ubuntu on a drive, I can't find the file after booting in to Windows 8". Which drive are you exactly talking about? The Ubuntu partition, or something on the Windows partition? What is this F partition? Is it the Ubuntu partition? Or is it a normal Windows partition that you use to save your data for example? Because if it's the Ubuntu partition, it will not be accessible from Windows because Ubuntu uses a special filesystem format that Windows does not understand. Please answer the questions I asked.

Comment: I have mentioned it now. :)

Comment: It's still not clear what partition you're saving the files to, only that it's some partition other than the one where Windows is installed. Can you tell us the full path (i.e., starting from `/`) of where you're putting the files *as seen in the Ubuntu system* as well as the output of `sudo parted -l`? (Please edit your question again to provide this information.)

Comment: are you hibernating windows?

Comment: Remember that windows can't read whatever you store in Ubuntu partitions, while Ubuntu can read both. Whatever you store in Ubuntu will only be accessible in Ubuntu, whatever you store in Windows will be accessible for both. Windows is designed that way. If you want tools to read ext2/3/4 partitions using Windows, I recommend you [su]

Answer (score 1):

By default, you will not be able to access Ubuntu's partitions from Windows because GNU/Linux uses the ext4 file system, which Windows does not understand. If you would like to access these files from Windows, there are a number of utilities which tell Windows how to deal with the ext file system family. Take a look at [this page](http://www.howtogeek.com/112888/3-ways-to-access-your-linux-partitions-from-windows/) for some solutions.

This is one way of interpreting at your question. However, after reading your question again, it sounds like what you are trying to ask is this:

"When I use Ubuntu to save a file onto a file system Windows should understand, Windows cannot read this file. Help!"

I can't really answer this question, but I dimly remember experiencing a similar problem, and I think I solved the problem by using a different flash drive. Re-formatting the drive might also help.

Comment: Yeah I can use different utilities  to read the ext4 partition from windows but the problem is, when I access the drive from windows the files saved in Ubuntu is being automatically deleted.

Answer (score 0):

As Josh mentioned above, Windows cannot understand how the read the Ext4 filesystem, which Ubuntu uses. (Ubuntu does not have the problem the other way around).

If you must share files, I would suggest one of 2 ways.

1. Mount the windows directory and write into the directory (eg the My Documents directory).
2. Create a new partition of type NTFS and write into that.

There is also software that you can install on Window to read the Ubuntu partition, but I cannot comment in how reliable that is.